# Creating a new WebDriver session reuse my cookies

Tags: webdriver, microsoft-edge

When I start a new WebDriver session in Edge and browse to a website I previously signed in (with "remember me" cookie persisted in Edge), the WebDriver session will re-use my cookie and appear as signed in.

Is it possible to start a WebDriver session under Edge as InPrivate mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just encounter that issue myself today so the only way I got it to work was pretty simple in the end. You have to check "Always clear this when I close the browser" in Edge settings (and select the things that you want to clear).

With that setting you will have clean session on each new driver initialization :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with a way to start Edge session in InPrivate mode, but as an alternative you can clean your cookies in the @Before step of each test.

For example:

```
@Test
public void deleteAllCookiesExample() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver(); //initialize with Edge here
    String url ="http://www.example.com";
    driver.navigate().to(url);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
}
```

Or delete cookies with specific name:

```
@Test
public void deleteCookieNamedExample() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver(); //initialize with Edge here
    String URL="http://www.example.com";
    driver.navigate().to(URL);
    driver.manage().deleteCookieNamed("__utmb"); //example cookie name
}
```

P.S. In previous IE versions there was a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5101) with it, that cookies were not accessible until you visit the page. So consider reloading the page after that or try something like (it work in IE11):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```

Comment: Its plausible but will also log me out of all online services used during development. Also it will not remove data in local storage, IndexedDB, etc.

Comment: @Compulim I see, good point. You can try and clean local storage with JavascriptExecutor (after the page loads): js.executeScript(String.format("window.localStorage.clear();"));